# make a hotkey to determine the orientation and the pivot point?

Tags: modeling, interface, shortcut

Is there a way to make a hotkey on the orientation and the pivot point? when you defined the workpiece of the two data: Global - active element, Norman - individual origins, view - 3D mouse ... etc.

like in MODO ...[image]

Comment: There already is a shortcut for selecting the orientation, `Alt Space`. I don't think there's a simple way to create a custom menu + shortcut to select the pivot point without some python. There are individual shortcuts however: `,` `.` `Ctrl ,` `Ctrl .` and `Alt .` (`Alt ,` toggles *Manipulate origins*)

Comment: it's just very slowly initially choose one then another ... and so just press one button and you have already configured a preset from. maybe macro ?

Comment: Also Ctrl + Alt + Space shortcut adds a custom transform orientation.

Comment: I see.. I think something like that could be cooked up with python perhaps

Answer (score 1):

Well, the 3D cursor really has no orientation...but orientation for any kind of transform already exists as local, normal, global and screen....they can be found at the bottom of the viewport near where you found the pivot point options(median point, cursor, individual objects, bounding box etc...)

but technically you can set a hotkey for the transform orientations in the user prefferences...they are already defined and you can see them merely by hovering over them with the mouse.